# why sqlite3_exec fails with callback abort-like symptoms?

Tags: c, sqlite

[from sqlite docuementation](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html)

> If an sqlite3_exec() callback returns non-zero, the sqlite3_exec()
>   routine returns SQLITE_ABORT without invoking the callback again and
>   without running any subsequent SQL statements.

gdbing function in which abort signal arise, it goes as follow

```
function() {
 ... // valid sql, valid non-null database pointer
 rc = sqlite3_exec(database, sql, callback, 0, &err_msg);
 ... // address of where sqlite3-exec expected to return to, but SIGABRT returns
}

callback(arguments***) {
  ...//read arguments content
  return 0; //the only local return statement
}
```

**the strange thing is**, if callback logic gets commented except return statement code works without SIGABRT, which implies that bug in the content, but gdbing callback function works without any errors until last return statement!

**edited**

**callback**

```
int readTable(void *pt, int argc, char **argv, char **colName)
{
  if(table == NULL) {
    table = calloc(1, sizeof(Table));
    table->ncol = argc;
    table->colname = malloc(argc*sizeof(String));
    table->coltype = malloc(argc*sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
      table->colname[i] = colName[i];
      table->coltype[i] = getDataType(colName[i]);
    }
    table->row = malloc(sizeof(Row));
    table->current = table->row;
    table->row->val = malloc(argc*sizeof(String));
  }
  else {
    table->current->nxt = malloc(sizeof(Row));
    table->current->nxt->val = malloc(argc*sizeof(String));
    table->current = table->current->nxt;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    if(!argv[i])
      continue;
    table->current->val[i] = malloc(strlen(argv[i]));
    strcpy(table->current->val[i], (const char*) argv[i]);
  }

  table->size++;
  return 0; //otherwise gets aborted
}
```

abort signal returns while sqlite3_exec, and not while callback executing, core dumped.

per @Ctx comment below, I mixed SIGABRT, and SQLITE_ABORT(assumed it return abort signal, but it doesn't). what happen is abort signal returns, while sqlite3_exec executing

Comment: And you have a proper function prototype of the callback function before calling `sqlite3_exec`? There's no other `return` statements in the callback function? Can you at least *try* to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes look above, i wrote it works while filling statements are commented, except return statement

Comment: Hm, it seems like you are mixing up an abort-signal (e.g. raised by an `assert()`  or `abort()` and the value SQLITE_ABORT returned by `sqlite3_exec()`. These two do not have anything in common except the name. I suspect, that the abort is raised by libc due to memory corruption.

Comment: @Ctx more details added

Comment: What catches my eye is, that there might be uninitialized pointers in `table->val[i]` because of `if(!argv[i]) continue;`. This will break somewhere in the future since you cannot distinguish between a valid and an invalid pointer then. Furthermore, your allocation is off-by-one for the strings (`malloc(strlen(argv[i]))`), better use `strdup()` to avoid such errors.

Comment: @Ctx but what won't lead to carsh(SIGABRT) right?!

Comment: @Error When corrupting the heap, an abort might very well occur. Did you fix the mentioned issues, still the same?

Comment: that was insightful, thx, works now, add fully detailed answer

Comment: yw, It's on the house ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**problem has no direct relation with sqlite3, but with callback implementation.**

as per @Ctx comment, I am mixing between SIGABRT, and SQLITE_ABORT, both has no implications on each others, SIGABRT returns in callback due to memory corruption caused by off by one uninitialized memory usage.

```
table->current->val[i] = malloc(strlen(argv[i]));
strcpy(table->current->val[i], (const char*) argv[i]);
```

has to be changed to

```
table->current->val[i] = malloc(strlen(argv[i])+1);
strcpy(table->current->val[i], (const char*) argv[i]);
//or
table->current->val[i] = strdup(argv[i]);
```

the same question callback snippet above is actually rubbish, it has other bug unrelated to memory corruption.